# Why is the first bracha after Yishtabach not a bracha?

Tags: tefilla, shema

In any checklist for saying 100 brachos a day, and based on the fact that we do not answer amen, why is the bracha that ends in "oseh shalom u'voreh es hakol" not considered a bracha?

It is not considered one of the "Birchot Shema" - why is that?

Answer (score 3):

The bracha that starts יוצר אור ובורא חושך doesn't end with עושה שלום ובורא את הכל.  It ends with ברוך אתה ה' יוצר המאורות, probably a few pages later in your siddur.

It's the first of the "Birchot Shema".